# How to drop a shape inside shape in VISIO using VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visio

I am using Rack-mounted Equipment (US units).VSS as stencil. I need to Connect a server on Rack. Please give an answer its urget...!

Answer (score 0):

Friend WithEvents AxDC As AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.AxDrawingControl

currentPage = AxDC.Document.Pages(1)
currentStencil = AxDC.Document.Application.Documents.OpenEx(File_name,VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked)

Dim shapeRack As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape = currentPage.Drop(currentStencil.Masters("Rack"), 1, 6)

Dim shapeSrver As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape = .Drop(currentStencil.Masters(“Server”), 0, 0)

''Here is the code...!

shapeSrver.Cells("BeginX").GlueTo(shapeRack.CellsSRC(7, 0, 0))

shapeSrver.Cells("EndX").GlueTo(shapeRack.CellsSRC(7, 1, 0))